# How to get first record and last record in a date

Tags: mysql

I have a table structured in below format :

```
**ID        StationID         Status        UpdateTime**
  1             1              xxxx      2014-09-25 00:01:05
  2             1              xxxy      2014-09-25 01:05:18
  3             1              xxxz      2014-09-25 09:23:05
  4             1              xxxx      2014-09-25 20:01:05
  5             1              xxxz      2014-09-25 23:21:34
  6             1              xxxz      2014-09-26 00:01:00
  7             1              xxxx      2014-09-26 01:45:24
  8             1              xxxy      2014-09-26 14:01:43
  9             1              xxxx      2014-09-26 22:01:27
```

For each day, I want to select first record and last record.
Here is result:

```
**ID        StationID         Status        UpdateTime**
  1             1              xxxx      2014-09-25 00:01:05
  5             1              xxxy      2014-09-25 23:21:34
  6             1              xxxz      2014-09-26 00:01:00
  9             1              xxxx      2014-09-26 22:01:27
```

Thanks all;

Comment: For future read [this](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html) please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
  from YOUR_TABLE yt
  join (select min(UpdateTime) minUpdateTime, max(UpdateTime) maxUpdateTime
          from YOUR_TABLE
         group by DATE_FORMAT(UpdateTime, '%Y-%m-%d')
       ) aggyt on aggyt.minUpdateTime = yt.UpdateTime or aggyt.maxUpdateTime = yt.UpdateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from mytable 
where UpTime = (select min(UpTime) from mytable group by date_format(UpTime,'%Y-%m-%d')) 
or UpTime = (select max(UpTime) from mytable group by date_format(UpTime,'%Y-%m-%d')) 
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from mytable 
where UpTime= (select min(UpTime) from mytable group by date_format(UpTime,'%Y-%m-%d')) 
or UpTime= (select max(UpTime) from mytable group by date_format(UpTime,'%Y-%m-%d')) 
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this by union

```
SELECT ID, StationId, Status, max(UpdateTime) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY DATE(UpdateTime)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, StationId, Status, min(UpdateTime) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY DATE(UpdateTime)
```

Just to add, to increase the efiiciency use UNION ALL rather than UNION (or UNION DISTINCT) as UNION requires internal temporary table with index (to skip duplicate rows) while UNION ALL will create table without such index.

If you want to do this by union and subquery

```
select * from table where id IN ( select max(id) from table GROUP BY DATE(UpdateTime) )
union all
select * from table where id IN ( select min(id) from table GROUP BY DATE(UpdateTime) )
```

If you want to do it by subquery

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE  id IN ( select max(id) from table GROUP BY DATE(UpdateTime) )
OR id IN ( select min(id) from table GROUP BY DATE(UpdateTime) )
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this will work

```
SELECT ID,StationId,Status,MAX(UpdateTime) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY DATE(UpdateTime)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,StationId,Status,MIN(UpdateTime) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY DATE(UpdateTime)
```

Comment: This assumes the MySQL extension for group by is active http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html